# How to get $d$ in terms of $A$ and $B$

Tags: logarithms

I'm trying to get $d$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ having the next equations:

$$0 = A + B*\log _2(d)$$
$$6 = A + B*\log _2(\frac{d}{2})$$

EDIT

How about $A$ in terms of $B$ and $d$? And $B$ in terms of $A$ and $d$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.**

$$
\log_2 \left( \frac{d}{2} \right) = \log_2 d - \log_2 2 = \log_2 d - 1
$$

Incidentally, a common abbreviation for $\log_2 x$ is $\lg x$.

Comment: Thanks! How about $A$ in terms of $B$ and $d$? And $B$ in terms of $A$ and $d$?

Comment: If you have $A$ and $B$ in terms of $d$, can't you use simple algebra to obtain the other things you want?

Answer (score 1):

The first equation gives you directly

$$d=2^{-\frac{A}{B}}$$

Comment: Thanks! How about $A$ in terms of $B$ and $d$? And $B$ in terms of $A$ and $d$?